# ncurses-like bindings in interpreted languages

Tags: linux, dialog, ncurses, interpreted-language

Are there any bindings for ncurses or a similar menuing framework in interpreted languages that make the process of creating console menus and interacting with options absurdly simple?

I want to quickly prototype out a terminal-only configuration utility that runs on a Linux machine, in order to leverage some local resources previously installed.

Answer (score 1):

There's a PERL module exposing CURSES:FORM and CURSES:WIDGETS, though I'm sure they're quite ancient. They may be fine for prototyping, however.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/tools.html#PERLCURSES

Comment: I don't think curses has changed in the past decade or so "quite ancient" probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

[urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/) for Python is pretty simple (see some [examples](http://excess.org/urwid/examples.html)) and is actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dialog utility](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/) might be what you want.

Comment: Hmm. That page references lxdialog as being the Kernel menuconfig software, which is the model I've had in mind. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The Python standard library comes with a [curses module](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) that you can use for this. Also, [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/curses.html) is a HOWTO.